# Expo - changing the project name without deleting the entire project in TestFlight

Tags: expo, testflight

Is it possible to change the name of an Expo project without having to go through the entire process of building it again and submitting to the app store?

I accidentally didn't update the project name in the app.json file and now am stuck with an app called `exmilti` in TestFlight.

It took a few days to build, submit, and get the approval for TestFlight so I would love to avoid that process if there is a simple fix.

When I attempt to rebuild it in the CLI with the new name I get an error:

> Reason: Unexpected response, raw:
>   {"responseId":"ed00c05f-82a0-41d6-9a7c-b48d04e68a1a","resultCode":35,"resultString":"There
>   were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and
>   re-submit.","userString":"Multiple profiles found with the name
>   'com.myComapanyName.AppName AppStore'.  Please remove the duplicate profiles
>   and try again."

Which means to me that I am going to have to fully remove the app from TestFlight (yikes) and then re-upload the newly named App and wait for them to approve it again.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I did not find an easier way so I just compiled the project and pushed it via expo again with the correct name.

It didn't take as long as I had expected.